# Baking normals from high poly to low poly mesh seems to remove all smoothing

Tags: normals, texture-baking, normal-map

I am trying to bake the detail (normals) of this high poly head:
[image: high poly mesh]

onto this low poly version:

[image: low poly mesh]

I'm using the standard process per various online tutorials - (1) create a new image texture and bring it into the shader graph on the low poly mesh's material, (2) select the high poly mesh and bake it into the low poly mesh's new image texture, (3) save the newly-generated normal map, (4) change the Color Space of the newly-generated normal map to 'Non-color', and (4) add a 'normal' node to the shader graph, hook up color from the Image texture generated normal map to the Normal node, and hook up the Normal node's 'normal' output to the 'Normal' input on the PrincipledBDSF material.

Now, the normal map seems to generate OK. There are some issues with it, probably I need to create a proper Cage for it.. but it's a normal map:

[image: generated normal map]

However the real problem is that for some reason when I hook up the Normal node to the PrincipledBDSF material, the model's shading goes from Smooth Shading to flat shading (polygonal) and doesn't appear to take on the normal map at all? The model ends up looking like this:

[image: low poly mesh with generated/bakes normal map applied - inexplicably flat-shaded]

I've worked on this a while now and have no idea what is happening to change the shading to flat shading. I have tried smooth shading the faces of both high poly and low poly prior to the bake process. Also smooth shading the low poly after the bake process. No success either way. What am I doing wrong here?

Screenshot of the whole thing at the end of the process, for clarity's sake:

[image: blender window at end of process showing setup]

Comment: You don't use a "normal" node to read a normal map.  You use a "normal map" node.  There may be other problems as well- colors on the normal map look pale, like you only switched to non-color after baking, and some of the deviations look overly strong-- but that's the first thing.  And working on anything else, would want a file (with high and low) to be able to help.

Comment: Ah that was the trick. Thank you!